# Can anyone explain to create custom Product Attributes Catalog Input Type for store owner field?

Tags: magento2, product-attribute

Can anyone explain to create grouped input text field in Product Attributes Catalog Input Type for store owner field?

I need to create an catalog attribute with grouped input text field. Please see below example:

```
Attribute Name: Specification
Text Input field 1: Density (kg/L)  
Text Input field 2: Kinematic viscosity (cSt) @40°C 
Text Input field 3: Kinematic viscosity (cSt) @100°C 
Text Input field 4: Cetane Index 
Text Input field 5: Sulphur content, %wt    
Text Input field 6: Water and sediments, %vol.  
Text Input field 7: Flash point, °C 
Text Input field 8: Pour point, °C  
Text Input field 9: Hydrogen sulphide (H2S)
```

Above fields are grouped with one "Specification". Please suggest me how to create attribute with above grouped type.

Thanks.